# Adding an image behind a table in HTML

Tags: html, css, background-image

Im working with some already created code for an email footer.  There is currently a background color behind the table, and I would like to switch this to an image.  I have the URL for the image, but am not sure what format that should be in img src= or url().  I am a beginner so please don't judge (I didn't write this code, it is the source code from our email provider)

I have tried a few different ways with no luck and just erasing the background color.

Here is the current code where I believe this should be edited?:

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
   <td class="ftrBG" style="padding: 5px; background-color: rgb(76, 78, 77);" align="center" width="100%">
    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="30" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
style="background-image: url('http://www.myimage.com/poops.jpg');"
```

You can use the background-image property.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp